# С помощью каких инструментов в Linux (Red Hat) можно доказать, что конкретноеJava-приложение генерирует конкретные DNS-запросы?

Tags: java, linux

Есть сервер на Red Hat Enterprise. На нем запущено приложение на Java.
Этим приложением генерируются DNS-запросы, среди которых есть много запросов на разрешение адресов подозрительных сайтов.
С помощью tcpdump и анализа дампа в wireshark определено и доказано, что подозрительные запросы есть. Однако, доказать что именно это приложение генерирует их удалось только эмпирическим путем.
Существуют ли средства/механизмы в стиле TCPVIEW для windows, которые бы позволяли определить соответствие между PID процесса и конкретным UDP-запросом?

P.S. Просмотр netstat/nethogs позволяет только увидеть факт, что конкретный PID обращается к DNS-серверу.

Comment: есть такой инструмент. программа *linux* называется. в частности, вас может заинтересовать подсистема этой программы под названием *netfilter*. см. [результаты запроса](https://www.google.ru/search?q=netfilter%20log%20pid)

Comment: "факт, что конкретный PID обращается к DNS-серверу." - а что нужно кроме этого? Ведь PID однозначно указывает на приложение. Если Вы подразумеваете, что доказано тоько то, что данное приложение вообще-то обращается к DNS, но не факт, что с подозрительными запросами, то решить эту проблему можно так:   из выдачи *tcpdump* определяете с какого порта отправлен данный подозрительный пакет. С помощью *lsof* определяете какое приложение владеет этим портом.

Answer (score 0):

С целью именно *доказательства*, когда PID уже известен, можно использовать `strace`, глядя в стороны sendmsg/recvmsg/read(), сопоставляя их с вызовами socket().